# Debugging WCF service library being hosted in a web application is not hitting break points

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2012

I have created a WCF Service Application(WAS hosted using IIS Express in VS 2012) project and a WCF Class Library in the same solution. When I run the solution the server app runs under IIS Express. My class library namespace is: Wfm.MarketManager.WebServices and the web app namespace is Wfm.MarketManager.WebServices.Web   In the Wfm.MarketManager.WebServices.Web I have a .svc file:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Wfm.MarketManager.WebServices.ListWebService" Factory="Wfm.MarketManager.WebServices.WcfServiceFactory" %>
```

I have another instance of VS 2012 with a web application that has a service reference to what is created from the WCF Service Application (http://localhost:12345/ListWebService.svc)  The service is getting called correctly, but my breakpoints are not getting hit inside of it. I remember this working in VS 2010 when creating similar projects. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an issue with my custom factory (WcfServiceFactory) I was not seeing in the debugger. Once I turned on `includeExceptionDetailInFaults` I saw where it was failing. Now it is stepping in fine. Strange thing, though, is that I had a break point in my factory. It is working now though.

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
```