# Debugging WCF services : Multiple Startup project

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

My solution constists of -

1. WCF service hosted on Visual Studio Development server. (Port 8001)
2. Web Application consuming services. (Port 8002)

I use start `multiple projects in debug mode` in visual studio solution.

Starting with WebApp debugging, I set few break points in WCF service code.

**Issue:**

WCF services breakpoint is not being hit. Although the code executes fine & returns the response to UI (WebApp)

These work fine when starting WebApp & Wcf services using two different solution.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: We've previously used a similar setup and were able to debug both fine. What version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: @AlexKey VisualStudio-2010

Comment: Perhaps take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157687.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770693/debugging-wcf-service-library-being-hosted-in-a-web-application-is-not-hitting-b

Comment: Is this just a debug issue? Maybe you are only attached to the process running on one port. Go to Debug -> Attach to Process... and make sure you are attached to both process runing on ports 8001 and 8002.

Comment: Is your web application on the visual studio development server as well?

Comment: @AlexKey WCF service & WebApp both are on development server.

Comment: @GabeThorns Based on your inputs, I rechecked.. `and found debugger was already attached to both the ports.`